# Image upload path not uploading in folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-uploading

I am having a problem when I try to upload the image on the folder and click upload,the image is not saved in 'UploadedFiles' folder.The 'UploadedFiles' folder is still empty and does not contain any picture.

This is my project directory of the saved image that it should go if it might helps:

//C:\Users\Drake\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DigitalWaterMarkTest\DigitalWaterMarkTest\UploadFiles

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here We will upload image with watermark Text
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(FU1.PostedFile.FileName);
    Image upImage = Image.FromStream(FU1.PostedFile.InputStream);
    upImage = ResizeBitmap((Bitmap)upImage, 400, 400);//new width
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(upImage))            
    {
        // For Transparent Watermark Text 
        int opacity = 128; // range from 0 to 255

        //SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity, Color.Black));
        SolidBrush brush2 = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity, Color.Red));

        Font font = new Font("Arial", 15);
        g.DrawString(txtWatermarkText.Text.Trim(), font, brush, new PointF(80,160));
        g.DrawString(txtWatermarkText.Text.Trim(), font, brush2, new PointF(200, 250));

        upImage.Save(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles"), fileName));
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/UploadFiles" + "//" + fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the event handler get hit when you set a break point? Any exceptions?

Comment: No exceptions,it just doesn't save my picture into "UploadFiles". i'm pretty sure I messed up the path that I provide which is this:     ("~/UploadFiles")